# Prepending a message with the size of the message

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking

I'm writing something server-client related, and I have this code snippet here:

```
char serverReceiveBuf[65536];
client->read(serverReceiveBuf, client->bytesAvailable());
handleConnection(serverReceiveBuf);
```

that reads data whenever a `readyRead()` signal is emitted by the server. Using `bytesAvailable()` is fine when I test on my local network since there's no latency, but when I deploy the program I want to make sure the entire message is received before I `handleConnection()`.

I was thinking of ways to do this, but `read` and `write` only accept chars, so the maximum message size indicator I can send in one char is 127. I want the maximum size to be 65536, but the only way I can think of doing that is have a size-of-size-of-message variable first.

I reworked the code to look like this:

```
char serverReceiveBuf[65536];
char messageSizeBuffer[512];
int messageSize = 0, i = 0; //max value of messageSize = 65536
client->read(messageSizeBuffer,512);
while((int)messageSizeBuffer[i] != 0 || i <= 512){
    messageSize += (int) messageSizeBuffer[i];
    //client will always send 512 bytes for size of message size
    //if message size < 512 bytes, rest of buffer will be 0
}
client->read(serverReceiveBuf, messageSize);
handleConnection(serverReceiveBuf);
```

but I'd like a more elegant solution if one exists.

Comment: My point is that the code works and I know it won't work properly using `bytesAvailable()` and I want to figure out a way to make it work without using `byteAvailable()`

Comment: @Kuba I'm aware, that's literally why I'm asking this question. If you didn't read the whole question (which I assume you didn't), I tried an alternative that sends the message size but it's cumbersome and I wanted to know if there was an easier way to handle that. If you missed the line where I acknowledge using `byteAvailable()` is bad, I can quote it for you. "but when I deploy the program I want to make sure the entire message is received before I handleConnection()."

Comment: You **absolutely have to** use `bytesAvailable`, just not to determine *message size*, but to determine *how much data is available for reading* :) You **also** have to send the message size. You **also** need to check `bytesAvailable` *prior* to reading the message size. The message size might be 2 or 4 bytes long, but you might have less than that many `bytesAvailable` to read :) [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24541844/1329652) shows how to do it.

Comment: @Kuba So with that answer, you're saying I have to use `bytesAvailable` to see if what it returns is equal to the `messageSize` I send initially, and then once it is emit a signal to process the data?

Comment: Yes. You **additionally** have to check it even before you attempt to access `messageSize`. There are no guarantees that the `messageSize` will come in one piece.

Comment: @Kuba And one last question about that answer, are you overloading the `readyRead()` signal or are you implementing a new slot called `readyRead()` and connecting it to the signal `readyRead()?

Comment: There's no way to overload a signal, since they normally are not virtual methods. You can't overload a non-virtual method. The whole reason for signal/slot mechanism is that you don't have to overload stuff.

Comment: @Kuba So I don't fully understand, would correct usage of the code you wrote look something like this? `connect(&m_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));`

Comment: Yes. The `this` argument is not even needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very common technique when sending messages over a stream to send a fixed-sized header before the message payload.  This header can include many different pieces of information, but it always includes the payload size.  In the simplest case, you can send the message size encoded as a `uint16_t` for a maximum payload size of 65535 (or `uint32_t` if that's not sufficient).  Just make sure you handle byte ordering with `ntohs` and `htons`.

```
uint16_t messageSize;
client->read((char*)&messageSize, sizeof(uint16_t));
messageSize = ntohs(messageSize);
client->read(serverReceiveBuf, messageSize);
handleConnection(serverReceiveBuf);
```

Comment: I'm having a problem when I do this. When I use `client->read((char*)&messageSize, sizeof(uint16_t));` the server crashes if the `messageSize` sent by the client is smaller (in bytes) than `sizeof(uint16_t)`. If I replace `sizeof(uint16_t)` with 1, then it will run fine. I'm prepending the message sent by the client with `char *bytes((char*)&messageSize);`, is there a way I can make sure that this will always take up a number of bytes equal to `sizeof(uint16_t)`?

Answer (score 0):

read and write work with byte streams. It does not matter to them if the bytes are chars or any other form of data. You can send a 4-byte integer by casting its address to char* and sending 4 bytes. On the receiving end cast the 4 bytes back to an int. (If the machines are of different types you may also have endian issues, requiring the bytes to be rearranged into an int. See htonl and its cousins.)